# Override how the value of a user defined class is displayed when it is a field of a structure

Tags: matlab, oop, enums

I have created my own class to act like an enumerated type.  I haver overridden the method disp() so when a variable containing that type is displayed in the Command Window it shows something meaningful (specifically, the name of that enumerated value.)

```
classdef MyEnumeratedType

    properties(Constant)
        ENUMVAL1     = MyEnumeratedType(1, 'ENUMVAl1');
        ENUMVAL2     = MyEnumeratedType(2, 'ENUMVAL2');
        ENUMVAL3     = MyEnumeratedType(3, 'ENUMVAL3');
    end

    properties(Access=private)
        ordinal
        name
    end

    methods(Access=private)
        function this = MyEnumeratedType(ord, name)
            this.ordinal = ord;
            this.name = name;
        end
    end

    methods
        function disp( this )
            disp(this.name);
        end
    end

end
```

So when I assign it to a variable in the command window, I get the desired output:

```
>> x = MyEnumeratedType.ENUMVAL2

x = 

ENUMVAL2
```

So far so good.  BUT when I assign a value of type MyEnumeratedType to the field of a structure, the display of that structure doesn't display the value, but only tells me that I have a value of type MyEnumeratedType.

```
>> mystruct.field1 = 42

mystruct = 

    field1: 42

>> mystruct.field2 = MyEnumeratedType.ENUMVAL3

mystruct = 

    field1: 42
    field2: [1x1 MyEnumeratedType]
```

How do I get the value of field2 to show up like it does for the double value in field1?

Answer (score 1):

The `disp` method for structures shows the contents of numeric and cell arrays, if they can be written in a row, and the class/size info otherwise:

```
s = struct('a',1,'b',[1 2 3],'c',{{1}},'d',magic(3),'e',[1;2])

s = 

    a: 1
    b: [1 2 3]
    c: {[1]}
    d: [3x3 double]
    e: [2x1 double]
```

Consequently, to have the value of your enum displayed, you need to overload `disp` for structures. To do this, you create an `@struct` directory on your path, and create your own `disp` method that hopefully reproduces faithfully what Matlab does, but with an exception for your particular class. In short: it's possible, but I'd rather not be the one doing that.

Comment: I've tried adding my own @struct/disp.m.  It gets called when you enter "disp(mystruct)", but not when you just enter "mystruct".  Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: @Clark: changing the behavior of user-defined classes is MUCH simpler, since all you need to do is define a `disp` method for that class that handles how the class output is displayed!

Answer (score -1):

This submission http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48637 attempts to recreate the `disp` function pretty well. So, you could use this for the `disp.m` you put in the `@struct` folder.